# What sort of Circular Dependencies does Oracle allow?

Tags: oracle, testing, cycle, circular-dependency

I am creating test cases and I need to cover circular dependencies. So far I have been able to create two tables such that Table A has a FK to B and B has a FK to A.

What other circular dependencies exist / are allowed between objects? I tried to create cycles between Views but Oracle successfully rejected that.

Comment: It puzzles me why someone whould want to create circular dependencies *on purpose*.

Comment: It's test data to ensure my app works correctly in their presence.

Comment: How about procedural code? You can have recursive calls in functions and procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make constraints deferred, such that they are checked commit time rather than at DML time. That might open some possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Package pck_a can reference pck_b and vice versa.

Take a look into `dba_dependencies` to see what what references what.

But, what are the test cases supposed to test? Maybe, with that knowledge, people here could give you better answers.